# Cannot able to get ParentId from ContentDocument

Tags: apex, contentversion, contentdocument

I have a below code to retrieve parentId of content document after insert on ContentVersion.

```
//get blob body content from ContentVersion
        for(ContentVersion cVersion : [SELECT Id, versionData,ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id IN : contentIds]){
            bodyContent.put(cVersion.ContentDocumentId,cVersion.versionData);
        }
        //get parentId from ContentDocument
        List<ContentDocument> contentDocs = [SELECT Id,Title,ParentId,FileExtension FROM ContentDocument WHERE Id IN: bodyContent.keySet()];
        for(ContentDocument cDocumet : contentDocs){
            attachmnetJobAppMap.put(cDocumet.parentId, cDocumet);
        }
```

But parentId is null. Could anyone please help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ParentId` on `ContentDocument` relates to the Library containing the document, not some record that the document is linked to. And a document doesn't **have** to be in a library, so it could be `null`.

See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm#ParentId-0A135AFF

If you're looking for the record that the document is related to, you might want to look at `ContentDocumentLink` (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm);

You could use a query like this:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLinks) FROM ContentDocument
```

Comment: yes . but still its not returning anything. Its is empty

Comment: Which one is empty? The ParentId, or the ContentDocumentLinks? Neither of them are required - a document can just exist by itself without being linked to a record or a library. If you have a particular document which you know to be linked to a record, that has no ContentDocumentLink, then something weird is going on. Otherwise, this sounds normal.

Comment: Its working. As you mentioned i got the parentId from ContentDocumentLinks.

Comment: Thank You Aidan!!